# How to extract characters from a string only if they are preceded by another substring

Tags: pandas

I have a column in a data frame that looks something like this:

| Contract |
| --- |
| Amend 001 randomgibberish |
| Amend 010 randomgibberish |
| Amendment 003 randomgibberish |
| randomgibberish 002 |
| randomgibberish 100 |

I am trying to create a new column containing only the amendment number of each contract. Specifically, if a string contains either 'Amend' or 'Amendment' and then a three-digit number, I want to extract that number and place it into a new column. My output would ideally look like this:

| Amendment |
| --- |
| 001 |
| 010 |
| 003 |
| NotFound |
| NotFound |

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: is that what you;re looking for?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
txt = ['Amend 001 randomgibberish',
'Amend 010 randomgibberish',
'Amendment 003 randomgibberish',
'randomgibberish 002',
'randomgibberish 100']

s = pd.Series(txt)
s.str.extract(r'Amend(?:ment)?\s(\d{3})')
```

```
    0
0   001
1   010
2   003
3   NaN
4   NaN
```